# Error loading component when backing again from the other component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

In the tab A, when I clicked on the button to show a tag value, it successfully shows. And then, when I chose tab C to do another task and back again tab A, I clicked button but it did not show tag value

This bug only occur when clicking tab C. And when I click tab B and then back again tab A, tag still normally show

Unfortunately, i cannot provide the code due to the project security requirements
I'm in use Angular 16. Thank you for supporting

Comment: Create a functional example in stackblitz for us to better understand the problem. You don't have to provide the code. Just to replicate the situation with dummy code.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're trying to ask but I need to see a bit of code or snippet to give you the solution, check if there will be some unknown issue are coming in console.

Comment: I want to give you snippet but my safety policy is strict in my company (i'm in use my company's laptop). Can you please give a bit your solution?

Comment: Please go through the code thoroughly and put console logs wherever you find some code is not working as expected, PLease check 
are you using any 3rd party UI Components/Library for tabs or just HTML/CSS/JS?

Comment: yes, i used primeng  and plotly.js to draw chart

Comment: Better if you reproduce the issue in the StackBlitz Sample Project. That would be helpful

Comment: i think i found the root cause for this issue. I'm conducting to fix bug. Thanks for your solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).